# Why didn't they introduce complete democracy in Westeros?

Tags: game-of-thrones

**Note:** This question is from out-of-universe perspective. And, I am looking for official answer.

In the end, after the wheel was broken, Lords of Westeros were looking for an alternate system of governance. Tarly even suggested to apply democracy to Westeros, but other Lords laughed at it.

Why didn't writers and directors choose to apply democracy to Westeros? It was the last episode of the TV series. What damage could it do?

Comment: .. besides, they had already written one of the worst endings of all times.

Comment: Because it would have been entirely out of character for them to have done so? You might as well ask why they didn't decide the Kingdom via a competitive limbo contest.

Comment: Why would they? Serious question. Just because it's a common modern governmental system? They aren't using other modern ideas either, and that makes perfect sense. The society of westeros is not similar to our modern society. Are you saying that there is some imperative that show writers push the idea of democracy through their works?

Comment: @Harabeck Democracy isn't a new concept. Ancient civilizations had successes with democracy.

Comment: @Valorum The question is not about what Lords could agree on. They were already fearful against a powerful army which wanted the wheel broken. Democracy could be introduced by lots of ways.

Comment: @Lobo That's not relevant to what I said. I'm trying to point out how random your question is. Why not ask why they didn't implement communism? Why didn't they implement a technocracy? Why didn't Jon wear more purple? These kinds of questions don't make sense with some implication of a reason as to why that would be the case. So why would it be the case that they would introduce democracy to Westeros? The only obvious answer I can see is, "because that's what I'm used to". And I don't see why that should matter to the writers for a fantasy show.

Comment: @Lobo, can you provide any evidence from the show to support your claim that the wheel had been broken?

Comment: @Harabeck That's not random. "Break the Wheel" had strong implication of it and Tarly even directly suggested it.

Answer (score 1):

Well D & D seemed to be TRYING to go for a “people don’t ever REALLY change” motif for the season. They attempted it with the undoing of the Jamie redemption arc as well. My take on your question was that despite all that happened and all the fighting for freedom from one king or another, they were all STILL holier than thou, arrogant, stuck up aristocrats who felt like they were better than everyone else simply because of the family they were born into, and had learned absolutely nothing from all they had suffered. That’s why they all laughed at Samwell for even suggesting it. It was basically saying “the more things change, the more they stay the same”.  That’s my take on it.

Comment: Yeah Daenerys didn't change at all...